# Trying to generate a dummy DataFrame but getting error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Objective:**

I would like to generate a dummy data frame to test certain functions but I am having trouble passing my array into a DataFrame.

**Situation:**

I would like to insert as my first column: `dates`, and the subsequent columns will either be strings or integers.

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col_names = ['Date', 'a', 'b', 'Dernier', 'Frequences', 'Total'] # 6 columns
data =[['2019-01-21',456,'dwfv84',23,74,261,4221],
['2019-02-10',123,'qwbe78',3,83,9251],
['2019-01-25',789,'adqw87',19,478,19195],
['2018-01-04',988,'afdi25',40,321,3753],
['2018-03-19',784,'asdf48',331,413,8551],
['2018-04-15',445,'asfv41',304,246,10215],
['2018-04-10',589,'sdqw88',309,80,19569],
['2018-05-20',741,'dsdg46',269,282,3108],
['2018-06-30',852,'cvgo87',228,261,5975],
['2019-01-19',963,'ewgs45',25,357,4405],
['2019-01-12',369,'fbbr54',32,197,1019],
['2019-01-18',258,'fwgs77',26,132,18100],
['2019-02-10',147,'jkyu87',3,32,8678],
['2019-02-05',753,'yukh20',8,132,19871]]

my_data= np.array(data)
datas = pd.DataFrame(data=my_data, columns=col_names)
```

**Error message:**

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 6
>
> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 14), indices imply (6, 14)

Comment: The first list in `data` has 7 elements, not 6, so remove the erroneous element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed the '74' from first row

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col_names = ['Date', 'a', 'b', 'Dernier', 'Frequences', 'Total'] # 6 columns
data =[['2019-01-21',456,'dwfv84',23, 261,4221],
['2019-02-10',123,'qwbe78',3,83,9251],
['2019-01-25',789,'adqw87',19,478,19195],
['2018-01-04',988,'afdi25',40,321,3753],
['2018-03-19',784,'asdf48',331,413,8551],
['2018-04-15',445,'asfv41',304,246,10215],
['2018-04-10',589,'sdqw88',309,80,19569],
['2018-05-20',741,'dsdg46',269,282,3108],
['2018-06-30',852,'cvgo87',228,261,5975],
['2019-01-19',963,'ewgs45',25,357,4405],
['2019-01-12',369,'fbbr54',32,197,1019],
['2019-01-18',258,'fwgs77',26,132,18100],
['2019-02-10',147,'jkyu87',3,32,8678],
['2019-02-05',753,'yukh20',8,132,19871]]

my_data= np.array(data)
datas = pd.DataFrame(data=my_data, columns=col_names)
```